# FOSUserBundle multiple firewalls + FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, firewall, fosrestbundle

I would like to setup FosUserBundle with FosRestBundle to manage a RestApi.
I already setup the FosUserBundle with my website, all works fine. But i want to configure two firewall_name in config.yml, one for the website other for the Api.

This my actual config.yml:

```html
# FOSUser Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    # config send mail
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
            from_email:
                address:        noreply@tickenet.fr
                sender_name:    WebMaster
        # surcharge des champs du formulaire
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
    from_email:
        address:        noreply@tickenet.fr
        sender_name:    WebMaster
    resetting:
        email:
            from_email:
                address:        noreply@tickenet.fr
                sender_name:    WebMaster
```

And i would like to code somethink like that:

```html
# FOSUser Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    # config send mail
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
            from_email:
                address:        noreply@tickenet.fr
                sender_name:    WebMaster
        # surcharge des champs du formulaire
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
    from_email:
        address:        noreply@tickenet.fr
        sender_name:    WebMaster
    resetting:
        email:
            from_email:
                address:        noreply@tickenet.fr
                sender_name:    WebMaster

# FOSUserApi Configuration
fos_user_api:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: api
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
```

Or can i specify multiples firewall in fos_user, like that :

firewall_name: main, api

Can someone help me please ?

Best regards,

Comment: Can you explain why you need two firewalls instead of using just one?

Comment: @xabbuh Example: Stateless api (without session) and web page to manage customer data (with session)